# How to get rid of react manifest.json error

Tags: syntax-error, manifest.json, json-server

I'm trying to use the json-server and when I run the command `json-server --watch jb.json` the home link, e.g., https://localhost:3000, is not rendered due to the following error in the console.

[image]

Essentially this image below is where I'm trying to land when clicking on the link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

✅ Solution: After asking around, I found that creating a json-server.json file in the root of your project and adding the following custom configuration works for me:

```
{
  .`.`.`,
  "static": "./node_modules/json-server/public"
}
```

Essentially, you call the home route, e.g., https://localhost:3000, from the static root directory, not the public directory, because it's located in your app. https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1100